# Join CentOS 7 to active directory

Tags: linux, active-directory, centos, redhat, samba

I'm trying to join centos 7 pc into Windows 2012 Active directory. I have installed these package as prerequisites.

```
sssd realmd oddjob oddjob-mkhomedir adcli samba-common samba-common-tools krb5-workstation openldap-clients policycoreutils-python
```

DNS is also resolving. But when I try

```
realm -v join -U 'administrator' vsis.tec
```

it's getting this error every time.

```
 [root@centos mnt]# realm -v join -U 'administrator' vsis.tec                     
  * Resolving: _ldap._tcp.vsis.tec
  * Performing LDAP DSE lookup on: 172.16.100.5
  * Successfully discovered: vsis.tec
 Password for administrator:
  * Required files: /usr/sbin/oddjobd, /usr/libexec/oddjob/mkhomedir, /usr/sbin/sssd, /usr/bin/net
  * LANG=C LOGNAME=root /usr/bin/net -s /var/cache/realmd/realmd-smb-conf.NOG5ZY -U administrator ads join vsis.tec
 Enter administrator's password:
 Failed to join domain: failed to lookup DC info for domain 'vsis.tec' over rpc: The transport connection has been reset.
  ! Joining the domain vsis.tec failed
 realm: Couldn't join realm: Joining the domain vsis.tec failed
```

Please help me to figure out the error and join the centos to the AD.

Thank You

Comment: Voting to close this question as off-topic. Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming related questions only. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here. The help also has a list of other SE sites that you can look through to find one appropriate for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have all the Active Directory ports opened from CentOS...

AD Ports list - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772723(v=ws.10).aspx

Thanks,
Ashish